# Parse numeric sequence into ranges of 20 at the command line

Tags: regex, bash, shell

For any sequential range of integers, `n1..n2`how can I use command line tools to parse them into ranges of length `<= n`?

#### Example

As a specific example, I have a directory with folders named `1253..2050`. Each folder has a script called `job.sh`, and I can submit them in batches of 20 jobs (since each node has 20 cores). Thus, I want to generate the following commands:

#### Sample input:

```
echo {1253..1301}
```

For a particular case I can generate this sequence of integers using either `/bin/ls` or `cat runs.txt`.

#### Sample output:

```
qsub -t 1253-1272 array.pbs
qsub -t 1273-1292 array.pbs
qsub -t 1293-1301 array.pbs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
count=20
off=0
dirs=(*)

while (( (off + count) < ${#dirs[@]} )); do
    qsub -t ${dirs[off]}-${dirs[off+count]} array.pbs
    ((off+=count + 1))
done
if [ $off -ne ${#dirs[@]} ]; then
    qsub -t ${dirs[off]}-${dirs[@]: -1} array.pbs
fi
```

That last `if` is probably not necessary in your case and this loop sort-of assumes that the ranges are going to be complete (I'm assuming `qsub` expects that too).

Comment: I am not sure if the condition is being met .. if I replace the qsub line with `echo TRUE`, I don't see any output. Am I missing something? Here is the command I expect to write "TRUE" a bunch of times: `while (( (off + count) < ${#dirs[@]} )); do     echo TRUE;     ((off+=count + 1)); done`

Comment: Did you populate the `dirs` array with the directory names?

Comment: I set `dirs={1253..1301}`

Comment: That's not an array that's a string. (It also doesn't expand the string. See `echo "$dirs"`.) Try: `dirs=({1253..1301})`

Comment: That's still a string and not an array. The snippet wants an array. `dirs=({1253..1301})` should create an array of those numbers.

Comment: I did. See my comment above. If I do `dirs=({1253..1301})`, `echo $dirs` only gives a single number, `1253`

Comment: Because `$dirs` for an array is the same as `${dirs[0]}` (i.e. the first element). Try `echo "${dirs[@]}"` or `declare -p dirs`. And I missed the first comment in that pair because of scrolling, sorry.

Comment: Thats it. Its only missing the final command when there are < 20 left  `qsub -t 1295-1301 /job.sh`. But its got 90% of what I need. Thanks

Comment: That last `if` doesn't cover that case? It does here with `dirs=({1253..1301})` http://ideone.com/P99Ixw

Answer (score 0):

try with this solution, may be can help you:

```
echo {1253..1301} | tr ' ' "\n" | awk '{print "gksub -t " $1 "/job.sh"}'
```

Comment: actually, I am trying to submit a range of integers. This submits each run as a separate job.